# How to create Unlock Slider type Custom Control in android?

Tags: android, image, custom-controls, slide

How can i create unlock slider with custom control in android? After unlock some event will be trigger and Some text(like **feedback**) will be placed in the middle of the control. *One image* will be placed at the *starting position* of that control which will be used for slide to end. And the *end point some image* will be placed like arrow.
Can anyone guide me to do this and some example sources also.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure you should make your custom SeekBar, create a class that extends the SeekBar class and override the onDraw method. also you could add some attributes like (text,leftimage and rightimage) so you could change them from the xml file.
About handling the text that should appear, you must add a onSeekBarChnangeListener and handle there everything you need.

Comment: i m also looking for same like this can you please share any examples for this?

Comment: i could write an example,but not wright now, i'm little bit busy with my job tasks. You could take a look at some other examples on how to create a custom view [From HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).
This is not hard

Comment: but i need same like this some examples Once you free can u please guide me how can i do this?

Comment: Thnx i think i will get shortly

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sliding Drawer for this purpose though this is deprecated. You can perform/apply  action onDrawerClosed and onDrawerOpen method while applying listeners to drawer.